# Java incorrectly UrlEncode \r to %5cr instead of %0D?

Tags: java, ascii, encode, urlencode, urldecode

I tried many online tool and in Java to encode the parameter, for example:

> A==\r

expect to get result as

> A%3D%3D%0D

but I end up get

> A%3D%3D%5Cr

I know that A%3D%3D%0D should be the correct output as it's a sign that I can successfully verify the encrypted data with RSA public key.

the encoder seems like encode "\" individually to %5c, but I need the encoder to see "\r" as return then encode it to "%0D"

I don't understand why I can never get \r encode correctly? 
if any missing information needed, please let me know, thanks.

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: [Works for me.](https://ideone.com/5oOa0d)

Comment: Where does the value `A==\r` come from? It's not a Java string literal, because the only way for URL encoding to return `A%3D%3D%5Cr` is for value to be `"A==\\r"`. Your value truly is the characters ``\`` and `r`, not a carriage return (CR) character.

Comment: @muchHAssle : If you don't vote for that answer I will delete it, That question is just a reputation seeker like this